# Деепричастие. Придаточное

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли к деепричастию добавить придаточное.

**Так же интересен тот факт, что он научился брать интервью, работая официантом, где задавал вопросы всем подряд.**

С уважением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же интересен тот факт, что он научился брать интервью, работая официантом **(в ресторане)**, где (= в котором) задавал вопросы всем подряд.

**Отвечаем не на вопрос о стиле речи, а точно  на заданный вопрос**: можно ли к деепричастию добавить придаточное?  Термин этот не точен, мы не добавляем придаточное к словам, придаточное может относиться или к опорному слову, или ко всему предложению.

Соответственно, и в данном случае **мы не прибавляем придаточное к деепричастию**, здесь опорным словом для придаточного служит **пропущенное существительное.** Именно к нему относится придаточное **определительное** предложение, средство связи ― союзное слово ГДЕ.

В других случаях само **деепричастие может служить опорным словом**, например:
Узнав, **что он работает официантом,** я был очень удивлен. Это придаточное изъяснительное, опорным словом является деепричастие (форма глагола) со значением передачи информации.

Answer (score 2):

***Также*** интересен тот факт что он...

Попробуем убрать "тот факт", зачем он? Это же канцелярщина. *Также интересно, что он...*

Идем дальше. Смысл не очень ясен. Попробуем прояснить, убрав деепричастный оборот: *Также интересно, что он научился брать интервью, где задавал вопросы всем подряд.* Гм... Где он вопросы задавал?! Очевидно, в ресторане, кафе или баре, в котором работал официантом. Так и надо писать: *работая официантом в баре, где задавал вопросы всем подряд.*

*Также интересно, что он научился брать интервью, работая официантом в баре, где задавал вопросы всем подряд.*

Все равно мне не очень нравится, но, думаю, сойдет.